# Selenium Webdriver in xpath object is not found

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am doing an automation with Selenium Webdriver using Java. I need to click the class name inside the span tag. 
Example

For this i used xpath to select class="selcteME" and used click(). This works fine if I put break point in debug mode but when I run the script without break point in debug mode object is not selected.

Please share if you have solution or suggest me how can I get the class name inside the span tag

() without xpath

Comment: Paste a snippet of the html you're having issues

Comment: I think the problem is that the element is not loaded yet, you should wait for it. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862866/how-can-i-overcome-element-id-exception-in-selenium/11863045#11863045

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium not finding element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853450/selenium-not-finding-element)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried by CSS Selector?

I suggest use some IDE to generate basic test and then use your logic.

Comment: While using CSS selectors and other location techniques is usually preferable to XPath, OP specifically says that the XPath expression works when debugging. This hints to a timing problem, not an XPath-problem.