# Selenium not finding element

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

This is the HTML:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiaw2u4j7dkmui2/Untitled%20picture.png

I don't understand why this code doesn't find the element on the page. The website doesn't use iframes.

```
@Test
public void Appointments() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary"));
}
```

this is the error message I get:

```
FAILED: Appointments
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary"}
```

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show any element with id `ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary`, does it? There's `Header1_liAppointmentDiary` however...

Comment: The id on your image is Header1_liAppointmentDiary **not** ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary

Comment: Is the element AJAX-loaded? Have you tried waiting for it, either [implicitly or explicitly](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)?

Comment: The link is currently broken. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Is this a timing issue? Is the element (or the whole page) AJAX-loaded? It's possible that it's not present on the page when you're trying to look for it, WebDriver is often "too fast".

To solve it, is either [implicit or explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

The **Implicit Wait** way. Because of the implicit wait set, this will try to wait for the element to appear on the page if it is not present right away (which is the case of asynchronous requests) until it times out and throws as usual:

```
// Sooner, usually right after your driver instance is created.
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Your method, unchanged.
@Test
public void Appointments() {
    ...
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary")).doSomethingWithIt();
    ...
}
```

The **Explicit Wait** way. This will only wait for this one element to be present on the page when looking for it. Using the `ExpectedConditions` class, you can wait for different things, too - the element to be visible, clickable etc.:

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.*;

@Test
public void Appointments() {
    ...
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary")))
        .doSomethingwithIt();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're searching for `ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary`, but there only is `Header1_liAppointmentDiary`, those are not the same...

```
ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary != Header1_liAppointmentDiary
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with `id="ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary"` in your html

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Header1_liAppointmentDiary"));
```

Should be

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Header1_liAppointmentDiary"));
```

Comment: I tried that as well but I get the same error message. I've tried using findElement by xpath, but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

try 
`driver.findElement(By.ClassName("MyAppointments"));`

If webdriver can't find an element by xpath or id, it is usually a good idea to try all the By options that could work

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I think the link you are trying to click is under a drop down or you need to mouse over something to see this link. If it is so then you will have make the element visible to perform the action.

Comment: If it only were invisible, the element would still get found. It would _not_ throw a `NoSuchElementException`. When you'd then try to interact with the element, it would throw `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Comment: I would expect the same, but I've just encountered this exact situation today as well. The element is not detected until I scroll down the page, making it visible.